# Trigonometry - calculate a value with sine and arccos

Tags: trigonometry

This is what I did so far:

> $\sin\left(2\arccos\left(1-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2\right)\right)\\=\sin\left(2\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\\=2\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\\=2\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\times\frac{1}{4}\\=\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$

What next? Can I simplify more or get to a result without using a calculator? Is there a better way to find a solution?

Comment: Please learn to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that your question may be editable by other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \arccos(1/4)$, so $\cos(\alpha) = 1/4$.
Recall the identity $\sin^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 1$, and solve for $\sin(x)$ to get:
$$\sin(x) = \pm\sqrt{1 - \cos^{2}(x)}$$
Now let $x = \alpha$ and replace. Note that we're going to take the positive value for the square root since alpha is in the first quadrant.
$$\sin(\alpha) = \sqrt{1 - \cos^{2}(\alpha)}$$
$$\sin(\alpha) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{16}}$$
$$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt{15}}4$$
Now back-substitute alpha for the result:
$$\sin(\arccos(1/4)) = \frac{\sqrt{15}}4$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\sin(\arccos(1/4)) = \frac{\sqrt{15}}8$$

This technique is useful for most compositions of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric functions. I'll leave it to you to verify that in general we have
$$\sin(\arccos(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^{2}}$$
Can you derive similar formulas for other compositions?

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+b^2=c^2\tag{Pythagorean Theorem}$$

$$\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}=1\tag{divide by $c^2$}$$

$$(\sin\theta)^2+(\cos\theta)^2=1\tag{Definition of sine and cosine}$$

$$(\sin\theta)^2=1-(\cos\theta)^2\tag{subtract $(\cos\theta)^2$}$$

$$\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-(\cos\theta)^2}\tag{take square root of both sides}$$

$$\sin(\arccos(r))=\pm\sqrt{1-(\color{red}{\cos(\arccos}(r))^2}\tag{$\theta=\arccos(r)$}$$

Since the result will be of the first quadrant, $\sin$ will be positive, hence

$$\sin(\arccos(r))=+\sqrt{1-r^2}$$

Comment: Hm, why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

let $$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$$
First notice that 
$$\sin(\arccos(x))=\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-(\cos(\arccos x))^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
and 
$$\cos(\arccos(x))=x$$
Therefore, with $x=\frac{1}{4}$ we have
$$\begin{align}\sin\left(2\arccos\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)&=\sin(2\theta)\\
&=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\
&=2\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{16}}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{8}
\end{align}$$